# Postgres: Select number of rows where date in tstzrange

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a table of `cases` with the column `period` of type *tstzrange* (see below)

```
              period
------------------------------------
 ["2018-06-14 21:19:55.802427+02",)
(1 row)
```

What I want to do is a query of the type

```
select count(*) from cases where 
  current_date is in range (period); # this last part is just pseudocode
```

I want to count the amount of rows where the `current_date` (just the day, month, year) equals the upper range of the range. How can I do this?

I looked into `upper_inc()` but couldn't quite understand how to use it with current_date.

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking for

Comment: I'm assuming you want to count all the records where the current_date is equal to the period column? You don't need to use parentheses on current_date it does not need any parameters.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala: updated the question text.

Comment: @kimdasuncion12 : indeed no paranthesis required, good catch.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `upper` to get upper bound timestamp, convert it to date and compare.

```
SELECT '2018-07-17'::date = upper('[2018-07-16 01:00:00,2018-07-17 06:00:00)'::tstzrange)::date
```